# Better way of aligning Views when a View is set to GONE

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a bit of a debacle here. I have a simple vertical linear layout where there are 2 textviews. The bottom textview will only be displayed if there is data for it from a web service call.

Currently what happens is, by default its set to `android:visibility="gone"` and when there is data for it, I set it to `android:visibility="visible"`. The issue I have is I need to top TextView to align centre in the view when the Bottom TextView is no longer visible. I know I could always set the layout params etc programmatically but I was thinking is there a better way to do this? For example somehow in the XML

View when both views are visible:

```
|--------LinearLayout--------|
|        TextView            |
|        TextView            |
|                            |
|----------------------------|
```

What the view looks like when the bottom View is set to GONE

```
|--------LinearLayout--------|
|         TextView           |
|                            |
|                            |
|----------------------------|
```

What I would like the View to end up looking like when the bottom TextView doesn't have data and is set to GONE:

```
|--------LinearLayout--------|
|                            |
|        TextView            |
|                            |
|----------------------------|
```

Thank you

Comment: you can set the layoutParams programmatically to layoutParams.Gravity = Gravity.CENTER.

Comment: yea, i know about that, i was just wondering if there was any other way to do this?

Comment: well, you can also use a relativeLayout and set the attribute of this textView to layout_centerInParent="true".

Comment: If you're not willing to do it programmatically, you can use relative layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it programmatically.

Lets suppose When you have no data from webservices then.

```
Textview tvTop;
Textview tvBottom;
```

after initializing the view you check

```
if(there is no data from webservices){
tvBottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
tvTop.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, i guess programmatically is the only way to do this...... was wondering if there is a better way